# Proper way to forward domain from Server A to Server B

Tags: seo, dns, forwarding

Here's my situation.

I register myweb.ca (country specific) domain with Webhost Provider A because they allow ccTLD, while Webhost Provider B does not.  I host my PHP files on Webhost Provider B at http://mysecretweb.com/myweb/ because I like them better (reliable, cheaper, proven etc...).

I want to achieve the following:

1. When user types http://myweb.ca/aboutus.html, they will see the contents of http://mysecretweb.com/myweb/aboutus.html
2. When user visits aboutus.html, the browser must display http://myweb.ca/aboutus.html, NOT http://mysecretweb.com/myweb/aboutus.html
3. The public and search engines CAN NOT BE AWARE of the domain http://mysecretweb.com/myweb because it is a secret.
4. Any solution offered must not negatively impact SEO

Will domain forwarding with masking solve my problem?  Any suggestions?

### Additional Detail

Someone suggested I change nameserver information from ns1.providerA.com to ns1.providerB.com.  Someone else counter argued that provider B will prohibit this because provider A is not on the network, and that provider B may ban my account for doing this.  I am confused...

Answer (score 1):

You could write one PHP script that gets an URL from $_GET, downloads it and passes to user (including headers) - and then some .htaccess Rewrite magic to point everything to that script. This is about the only way that is entirely transparent to both humans and bots.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and detect bots and humans apart and have diferent actions for the 2